# How to surround flutter widget in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Just wondering if there is a shortcut or extension in visual studio code to surround a code block - or more specifically highlight the widget name and then surround that widgets children.

Often is the case where I have created, lets say a:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Container(
  ...
```

But then after some writing, i want to surround that `Padding` with something else, like a `Column` or `Row`.
As is, I need to prefix the `Padding` with `Row( child:` and then scroll down and add the new ),` bracket

Is there not a way to just select the `Padding` and then tell vs code that I am going to prefix this so add the bracket for me?

Pretty sure I have seen this in action in IntelliJ

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Sure!

Vscode offer a few refactor options, including `Wrap with Column`:

[image]

Just right-click on a widget and press "Refactor".

Comment: Great, to bad Google forgot to mention this on the Flutter website. There they just state to use Alt+Enter

Comment: how to delete a widget any shortcut?

Comment: that worked nice.   I saw it demonstrated but didn't see the refactor option demonstrated.  This feature will save me time.  Thanks

Comment: Anyone know if this list of wrappers is extendable/customizable ? I would like to add my own or perhaps create an extension that adds more.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra ALT+Enter is on Android Studio.  Does VS  Code have a hot key for this?  Nmd, see next answer.

Comment: Also, on Mac, you can use the hotkey Shift + ^ + R

Comment: @Bawantha to delete you should tap on another widget, this command also show delete options if available

Answer (score 106):

Place your cursor in the widget you want to edit and use `CTRL + .` shortcut to see the options. Use `CMD + .` for MacOS. That will do it.

Comment: `CMD + .` for MacOS. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was looking for this, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

⚠️ If `wrap with Column` is not shown on *Right-click* - refactor:

- on *Window* : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
- on *MacOs* :  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>.</kbd>

Then *Right-click* > `wrap with Column`

---

Here is the reason why this happen: https://dartcode.org/docs/refactorings-and-code-fixes/ .
Also documented there: you can now bind shortcuts to the refactor actions:

> `Ctrl`+`.` in Code opens the “lightbulb” menu showing all code fixes/refactors. Code v1.20 gained the ability to [keybind](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_keybindings-for-quick-fixes-and-code-actions) quickfixes. To do this you should edit your keybindings.json file and include the ID of the refactor as found below.

Answer (score 21):

On VS Code on Windows just right-click on any widget and press "Refactor" or use the keyboard shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

If any one looking for Android Studio its `option + return` in Mac and `Alt + Enter` in Windows.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment on the question. People will be able to see this much easier.

Answer (score 6):

Simply press:
`Ctrl + dot` on windows
or
`Command + dot` on mac

and a list pops up showing wrapping options!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the widget and choose 'refactor', then 'wrap with new widget'

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu VSCode it is also ctrl + . where as in Ubuntu Android Studio or Intellij it was alt + enter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the widget
2. Press CTRL + SHIFT + R

Answer (score 0):

I have been installed a plugin "key promoter X", and it offers you shortcuts on actions you do in IDE. Then you are wrapping once via context menu, and it offers you a shortcut, set or manage, and I have adde "cmd + W" to wrap with a widget. Very useful.