# No Flutter Widget menu for wrapping in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Update: This happens when/if you are working with **"Plugins"**. When you have a subfolder / project containing examples and you open the plugin folder in VS Code. Then you are unable to use the menu and the cool wrapper stuff.

From the VS Code [description](https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/vs-code#assists--quick-fixes), there should be an assistent if I right click on a widget, but I see non?

Note: Yes I have installed the extension ;-)

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale en-DK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.29.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: Did you try just using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + .`?

Comment: I am on a danish keyboard, and the keyboard shortcut did not work. When I found that the was no menu for wrapping, when right clicking - I was/am thinking, that maybe there is a little bug.

Comment: Right click and select `refactor` link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379831/how-to-surround-flutter-widget-in-vscode/52383406?noredirect=1#comment93691691_52383406

Comment: That is the problem :-) No menu

Comment: That is strange. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I have no idea, but it is suddenly there - I will delete this as there is no answer. Thanks for looking

Comment: I now know what it is - I will describe it in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Windows:
Select the word, e.g. Container and right click and select REFACTOR.

Answer (score 2):

Vscode offer a few refactor options, including Wrap with Column:

Right click on a widget and click "Refactor" on the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

press `ctrl+shift+R` to refactor in windows.