# Refactor flutter code not avilable in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, refactoring

vs code suddenly not showing the refactoring option on any code on dart.. If I press ctrl+shift+R on any widget or class it says no refactoring [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ki52.png)available..

Comment: Have you tried restarting your analysis server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place your *cursor* in the widget you want to edit and use `CTRL + .` shortcut to see the options. Use `CMD + .` for MacOS. To do it manually in VS Code.

*And For Android Studio its `option + return` in Mac and `Alt + Enter` in Windows.*

[See this For A Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52379941/9577961)

Comment: Already found the solution, but thank you anyway.. this is the available solution for now..

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I'm running to the exact same issue and the answer above is irrelevant

Comment: option + return does not work on Mac. I am using M1 Macbook Pro 2020 and this did not help in Android Studio!

Answer (score 1):

Turning dart lps analyzer off solved the problem for me[image]